# google sheets javascript filter multiple sheets based on dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a user access review spreadsheet with multiple tabs of different user listings.

I have the main tab called 'Mgr Selection' which I would like the manager to select their name from a drop down list.

I would then like all of the tabs to filter based on that manager's name.  The manager name is on different columns based on the user listing.  The code below is just for one tab called 'GitHub', which I am trying to filter Column D for the Mgr Name (which is the data variable).

I wrote the below but I am getting an error.

```
function setFilter() {

    var mgr = spreadsheet.getSheeyByName("Mgr Selection");
    var GH = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("GitHub");

    var lastRow = GH.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn = GH.getLastColumn();
    var range = GH.getRange(2,4);
    var data = range.getValue()

    var filterSettings = {};
        filterSettings.range = {
        GHsheetID: GH.getSheetId()
    };

    filterSettings.criteria = {};
    var columnIndex = 4;
    filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
        'hiddenValues': <> [data]
    };

    var request = {
        "setBasicFilter": {
```

> syntax error for `setBasicFilter`.  Syntax error. (line 23, file "Code").

```
"filter": filterSettings
  }
};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, GH.getID());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, questions like this will not get much traction here. You are asking "How can I accomplish this?" when typically, SO only answers questions like: "Why does my code not work? Here's my code, here's my error, here's what I've tried..." Take the time to understand the difference, but it's not the end of the world - everybody does it when they're first starting out on SO. When you have a more appropriate question, we will be happy to help. I recommend starting with some Google searches or try over at Super User (they're less critical there).

Comment: I am trying with the code. I will update.

Comment: Good job. Please see my edit, and put the actual error after the `>` - this is typically what you do to mark an error. Don't forget to upvote people that are helping you out. Also try to make the question more succinct.

Comment: Thank you @TravisHeeter! I made the question more succinct and put the error in the correct place in the code.

Comment: Try writing your `request` differently, such as `var request = {}; request.setBasicFilter = {}; request.setBasicFilter.filter = {}; request.setBasicFilter.filter.range = range; request.setBasicFilter.filter.criteria = criteria;` except put all that on separate lines. Then maybe the error will give you a more specific line it has the problem with.